# Square root and sum of odd numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have found this on internet as a very interesting mathematical curiosity...

> If we have $x\in \mathbb{N}$, they say that if $x=\sum^{K}_{n=0}{(2n+1)}$, then $\sqrt{x}\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sqrt{x}=K+1$.

Is that always true? Why?

This is my first question here! Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! This has been discussed on this site many, many times before, and you will probably enjoy reading some of the many explanations that have been given

Comment: Nice, thanks for the heads-up! This is very good, indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is my favorite fact!

Consider this.

It's true that $1=1^2$

And it is true that $1+3=2^2$ and that $1+3+5=3^2$

Suppose it were true that $1+3+5+.....+(2n-1)=n^2$.

Then $1+3+5+.....+(2n-1)+(2n+1)=$

$n^2+(2n+1)= $

$n+2n+1=(n+1)^2$.

So if it's true for some it is true for the next.

Also.

Consider:

$N= 1+2+......+n $

Then $2N=N+N=$

$1+2+......+n+$

$n+......+2+1=$

$(n+1)+(n+1)+..... +(n+1) =$

$n (n+1) $

So $N=n (n+1)/2$

So $\sum (2k-1)=2\sum k -\sum 1$

$=2*\frac {n (n+1)}2-n$

$=n (n+1) - n=n^2+n-n=n^2$.

I love it.

Comment: Very nice answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint, look at the sequence of squares:

$0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25$

Then look at the differences:

$1, 3, 5, 7, 9$

Formally, $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 - n^2 = 2n + 1$. Does that illuminate the problem?

Comment: yes!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the sum of an arithmetic progression of $N$ terms is $N$ times the average of the first and last terms. In this case: $\;x = (K+1) \cdot \cfrac{1 + (2K+1)}{2}\;$.